# Почему неверно рассчитывается факториал?

Tags: алгоритм, kotlin, факториал

Всем привет. Я написал функцию для расчета факториала. И все вроде ок, но потом проверил и выходит что после 12! результат неверный. Проверял в Гуле, и на сторонних сайтах.

Код

```
fun factorial(num: Int): Int {
    if( num!=1 ) {
        return num * factorial(num-1);
    } else return 1
}
```

В чем проблема? Сам код вроде правильный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно сказал коллега выше - Int слишком мелкое для таких расчетов. Для этих целей пригодится BigInteger. Вот пример кода

```
fun calculateFactorial(num: Int): BigInteger {
    var n = BigInteger.ONE
    for (i in 1..num) {
        n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i.toLong()))
    }
    return n
}
```

В коде выше мы объявляем переменную n с типом BigInteger. ONE - константа равная 1. То же самое можно получить и так

```
var n = BigInteger.valueOf(1)
```

но с ONE просто короче и красивее. Далее в цикле мы рассчитываем n вызвав метод multiply у BigInteger, который умножает n на параметр, передаваемый в multiply.

На этом сайте кстати нашел пример расчета [факториала с помощью корутин](https://fox-code.ru/a/vychislenie-faktoriala-kotlin/). Может полезно будет, почитайте. Мне кажется с корутинами скорость будет выше.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде помогло!

Answer (score 3):

13!=6227020800

А это число в 32-битное уже не помещается никак...

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. А что вообще используют для подсчета больших чисел в Kotlin? Только BigInteger как посоветовали ниже?

Comment: А это уже к специалистам по Kotlin - я только проверил в Интернете, что размер int'а в Kotlin - 32 бита...

Comment: все равно спасибо!